# Angularjs parent scope use the child scope'attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('Parent',['$scope',function($scope){
    //define nothing  
}]).controller('Child',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.user={username:''};//define an object user
}])



<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Parent">
        {{user}}<!--print nothing-->
        <div ng-controller="Child">
            {{user}} <!--print an object-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to deal with the problem above without using the inject of `$rootScope`

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: i want the parent user print the value of child user without using $rootScope

Comment: Downvoting this is rather harsh considering they are new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: always people who downvote without explanation !

Comment: @jusopi, I don't agree, I don't think being new to StackOverflow should give you a free pass. 
I downvoted, because the question is wrong, it is basic angular behaviour that is well documented. My take on an explanation is below. 
In short: a childScope has inherited all objects and functions from his parent, a parentScope can't inherit from its children. So it only works in 1 direction. Not using $scopes makes this **very easy** to understand.

Comment: I'm not saying they should get a free pass, I'm saying make the reprimand in the form of constructive criticism and possibly an answer. At the time there was simply a downvote with no explanation of why.  At least you have no addressed **why** he's getting downvoted.  Regarding *controller-as* syntax, that's something I advocate as well but with most of the angular documentation not written in that context **and** this user's lack of understanding simple scope inheritance, I think it's somewhat advanced right now.

Comment: Ah, simply downvoting without being constructive is never okay. We should rewrite the angular documentation, and get all $scope-based code refactored! :) @CeryDe, check out http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro this is a tutorial sponsored by the angular-team (you know, Google), and is a really good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment...

> i want the parent user print the value of child user without using $rootScope

... you can't accomplish this because the parent scope cannot *inherit* from the child scope as it is currently defined.  View controllers inherit from their parent controllers based on their node structure.

```
<parent-node>
    {{user.name}} 
    <hr/>
    <child-node> 
        <!-- user inherit from parent node's scope by default -->
        {{user.email}}
    </child-node>
    <another-child-node> 
        <!-- user inherit from parent node's scope by default -->
        {{user.someOtherData}}
    </another-child-node>
```

You either need to define the `user` on your parent scope like so:

```
.controller('Parent',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.user = {};
}])
.controller('Child',['$scope',function($scope){
}])
```

... or you can handle this via a directive depending on the end User-eXperience.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that returns when people use $scope without reading up on the scopes documentation. 
This is why I always tell people not to use $scope to bind objects / functions to. Well this and maintainability.

**CONTROLLERS:**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('Parent',['$scope',function(){
        //define nothing
    }])
    .controller('Child',['$scope',function(){
        this.user = {username:''}; //define an object user
    }]);
```

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Parent as parentCtrl">
        {{ parentCtrl.user }} <!-- undefined -->
        <div ng-controller="Child as childCtrl">
            {{ childCtrl.user }} <!-- object -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```